# Power BI - I am using SSAS model as Db source. How can I add a column to the report coming from Oracle Function without to modify the model?

Tags: oracle, powerbi, ssas

I have little experience in power Bi stuff, I am building a report and we are using SSAS model as database. I would like to add 2 columns which should call oracle functions. I am trying to add new columns to the report but it seems when I choose SSAS as database, I cannot use the Modeling options in the main menu ( New column, new table, new parameter, etc )

[image]

I tried to add a measure as new field ( it is the only option enabled in the Modeling menu), but I don't know how can I call my Oracle function using a measure.. Can I do that?

Please notice I am using a SSAS model..
Can I use different sources of data when I am using SSAS to get data?, we don't want to modify the model, we want add a new column directly in Power BI which should call a oracle function..

Some suggestions to add my new columns which should call Oracle functions?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting PBI to SSAS using [Live Connection Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data), and don't have the modelling options. You can use the new preview of [Direct Data Sources](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/directquery-for-power-bi-datasets-and-azure-analysis-services-preview/) on SSAS and Power BI Datasets. This will give you some options to add items.

You cannot call a Oracle function via a measure or column. This would have to be done in the database level before it gets to Power BI and the SSAS model.

You can connect to the SSAS model in import mode, but you'll have to create the SSAS model again in Power BI, and still not be able to use the Oracle function in your import process directly. If you can connect the the database, to may be able to write an SQL query that can be used in the import that calls the function. But again you'll have to recreate the SSAS model in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

Use import mode instead of direct query,

Direc query is not recommended unless you want live update.